# Programmatically adding buttons in a list on Swift 5

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I'm relatively new to swift and coding in general, I'm currently trying to develop an app that essentially operates like a to do list. My goal for the home page is pretty basic. The logo centered at the top and a button to create "New Lists". I've gone back and forth on how to manage the various lists (using buttons or using listviews). But ideally I want the New List button to create a new button (which accesses the newly created list) and also take the user to the newly created list to name it and add contents etc.

I'm currently exploring the use of NavigationLinks and Navigation View (Code Below)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingNewList = false
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                VStack(spacing: 30) {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("This is gonna be a new list"), isActive: $isShowingNewList) { EmptyView()}
                
                Button("New List!!") {
                    self.isShowingNewList = true
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .offset(y: -100)
            }
                .navigationBarTitle("Nudge")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm thinking navigation view is not the way to go because even when creating a button to control the link it controls the entire screen. Any pointers?

[image: I've added an image to give a bit more description]

This is a complex question so any sort of guidance or suggestions of strategies that could be worth looking into would be great!

Comment: *Any pointers?* yeah, here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

Comment: This isn’t complex it is a basic setup. The sample code that comes with a new SwiftUI project does this. A little different setup but same concept.

Comment: Put the destination as a new view, then have another `NavigationLink` in that to go to _another_ view. You can embed `NavigationLink`s as far as you want to navigate